# Downvotes: When is Maika Sakuranomiya's birthday?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[When is Maika Sakuranomiya's birthday?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55825/when-is-maika-sakuranomiyas-birthday)

This closed post of mine has been heavily downvoted.  Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments,

> ...because the answer can be found easily, even by searching the title only. The tooltip for the downvote says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"